# kvs_gstreamer_sample, how to deal with intermittent rtsp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gstreamer, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm using the command `kvs_gstreamer_sample` (3.3.1) from the AWS kinesis video streams producer (sdk-cpp). I run the following command to copy an rtsp stream to KVS:

```
./kvs_gstreamer_sample DemoStream rtsp://foo.bar
```

The problem is that such a stream is not always available (quite the opposite, it's available only a couple of minutes per day). In those cases, the kvs_gstreamer_sample returns. Is there a way to keep checking for an intermittent stream availability?